# jqGrid: mess when cellattr returning string containing "style"

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jqgrid

**Background:**

I've encountered strange behavior in `jqGrid`: when `cellattr` callback returns string containing "style" the grid gets messed.

**Please see an example:**

**HTML:**

```
<table id="grid"></table>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: "auto",
    data: [{column1: "row1col1", column2: "row1col2" },
        {column1: "row2col2", column2: "row2col2" }],
    colNames: ['Column1', 'Column2'],
    colModel: [
    {
        name: 'column1',
        index: 'column1',
        cellattr: function (rowId, val, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
            attrValue = (rawObject.column2 == 'row2col2') ? 'GangnamStyleAttribute' : 'GangnamAttribute';
            return ' customAttr="' + attrValue + '"';
        },
        width: 100
    },
    {
        name: 'column2',
        index: 'column2',
        width: 100
    }],
    caption: "Stack Overflow Example",
});

$("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam');
```

Also please see a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5XzVM/3/)

In the example above `cellattr` returns *' customAttr="GangnamAttribute"'* for the first row and *' customAttr="GangnamStyleAttribute"'* for the second row.

As you can see from [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5XzVM/3/), the first row is displayed correctly, but the second one is messed up: the first column is not shown and the second column is displayed in place of the first one.

This happens if `cellattr` returns something containing the substring "**style**" in it.

**Question:**
Is there any solution or work around for this problem, allowing to set attributes with values containing the word "**style**"?

Comment: One will have to fix the code of jqGrid (see [the part](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L1095-L1109) of the code) to be able to use attributes which name or value includes `style`, `title` or `class` substrings. I personally would prefer to allow `cellattr` to return object  and not string only. For example `{customAttr: "GangnamAttribute"}`.

Comment: @Oleg Nice! I didn't know that cellattr can return object instead of string. I'll try and will let you know whether this helps. Thanks!

Comment: You understood me in a wrong way. I mean that one have to fix the code of `cellattr`, but I don't mean that *the current code of jqGrid* allows to return object from `cellattr`. I suggest you don't modify the parsing of the string returning by `cellattr` (see the code `formatCol`). Instead of that one can use `if(typeof celp === "string") {/*existing code*/} else if (celp != null && typeof celp === "object") {/*new code*/}`. [The part of the code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L1221-L1247) could help you probably.

Comment: @Oleg, thanks for clarification. I think I found a simple work around for my problem. jqGrid attempts to extract from the string, returned by cellatr style attributes in order to append the returned styles to already existing cell styles. jqGrid searches for the first occurrence of 'style'. So my work around is to prepend the returned string with empty style attribute: return ' style="" customAttr: "' + attrValue + '"'

Comment: Just had a live bug raised with this issue, blew my mind until I found this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a simple workaround for my problem.

The problem occurred because `jqGrid` attempts to extract the style attribute from the string, returned by cellatr. It works this way in order to append the returned styles to already existing cell styles. jqGrid searches for the first occurrence of 'style'.

So my workaround is to prepend the returned string with empty style attribute:

```
return ' style="" customAttr: "' + attrValue + '"'
```

See [jsfiddle with the workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/5XzVM/8/)

Comment: Thanks for finding this. Drove me crazy just figuring out what was triggering the breakage. Pretty silly that the jqGrid developers didn't at least exclude keywords that are within quotes from their little parsing logic.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still encountering this problem, this bug was reportedly fixed in [jqGrid 4.7.0](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:changetwo#jqgrid_4.7.0_changes_and_fixes) so upgrading jqGrid should solve your problem.